# For-loop not executing File writing commands

Tags: java, for-loop, io, printwriter, bufferedoutputstream

I have a program that is supposed to generate a file with a random integer name and append 200 characters of data to each file. I have already succeeded in being able to create a file:

```
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(
         new File("C:/Users/mirvine/Desktop/SPAM").toPath()));
```

And I have gotten it to write `char`s to the file:

```
bos.write((char)rand.nextInt(255));
```

But when I combine the two with a for loop, it doesn't work:

```
try {
            while(true) {
                int i = rand.nextInt();
                File outputFile = new File("C:/Users/mirvine/Desktop/SPAM/"+ String.valueOf(i) +".txt");

                    bos = new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(outputFile.toPath()));
                    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(bos);
                    for(int qu = 0; qu <= 2000; qu++) {
                        writer.write((char)rand.nextInt(255));
                        System.out.println("Total " + String.valueOf(qu) + " characters written to " + String.valueOf(i) + ".txt!");
                }
                    System.out.println("File named \'" + String.valueOf(i) + ".txt\' created!");

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace(); return;}
```

I will get the output "Total: (number) characters written to (whatever).txt!" but it won't actually write the characters. However, if I make the loop infinite (by changing `qu++` to `qu--`) it will write the characters, of course with only one file though. I even tried changing it to a `while` loop and it didn't  work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider changing the use of `BufferedOutputStream` and `PrintWriter` for [FileWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html), which will take your file as an argument to the constructor.

Also, make sure you flush and close the stream after finishing with it.

Comment: I didn't feel the need to close it because it was supposed to go on for infinity, but I did forget to flush, and I noticed that I defined it inside the `while` loop and should close it. That was my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `BufferedWriter`, it's more efficient, and don't forget to close it at the end. The infinite loop is useless.

```
int i = rand.nextInt();
File outputFile = new File("C:/Users/mirvine/Desktop/SPAM/"+ String.valueOf(i) +".txt");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));  
for(int qu = 0; qu <= 2000; qu++)
{
    bw.write((char)rand.nextInt(255));
    System.out.println("Total " + String.valueOf(qu) + " characters written to " + String.valueOf(i) + ".txt!");
}
bw.close();
```

Comment: Whilst viable, it's recommended to use FileWriter instead of OutputStreamWriter when writing character data to files, as it will automatically setup character encoding. Nice tip about wrapping it in a BufferedWriter, though! Forgot the raw FileWriter wasn't buffered...